# Android Wear BLE Central Role

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os

Is there any limitation for an Android Wear smart-watch to connect via BLE to a device that is not a smartphone to read data? An example is if for example a microwave oven was able to send a message indicating that it is complete, could an Android Wear device consume this data?

I am not sure if Android Wear devices are restricted to only communicating with smartphones, or if they cannot operate as a central device.

Comment: Anything new on this topic?